# Django having a trouble seems like its not making the basic primary key id for some reason

Tags: django-models

The above exception (column movies_app_my_watch_list.id does not exist LINE 1: ...022-02-16T01:03:45+00:00'::timestamptz) RETURNING "movies_ap... ^ ) was the direct cause of the following exception: